# Which application can be recommended to save a whole site recursively off line?

Tags: ipad, web-browsing, network

I have a tourist web site I want to archive for off line view on my iPad.

I want to crawl and save it in 2nd and 3rd level depth.

Which application can be recommended to save a whole site recursively off line?

Comment: Do you want an iPad app that does this, or an application for another platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SiteSucker](http://www.sitesucker.us/home.html) is a great tool for this. They have both a [Mac version](http://www.sitesucker.us/mac/mac.html), and a [iOS version](http://www.sitesucker.us/iphone/iphone.html). I have used the Mac client a while ago.

If you want to do this on the computer, ['wget'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) is a great tool, and the `-m` flag will help you mirror the site to a local directory. You may have to install `wget` through homebrew or another similar tool.

Answer (score 0):

There's an app called SiteSucker that allows you to download websites. I haven't tried the iOS version, but used the desktop version extensively and happily with basic websites that I used to support/create. There were some issues with PHP sites where the resource files wouldn't come down, just the pages themselves would get retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Offline pages and Offline page pro are also the apps which can be installed on iPad and where you can save the entire Website and view it offline.

Reference link:
https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/offline-pages-pro-offline/id391462107?mt=8